# Character on $\Gamma_{0}(4)$ and generalization of Dedekind symbols

Tags: group-theory, modular-forms

It is known that the congruence subgroup $\Gamma_{0}(4)$ is generated by 
$$
T=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, R=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 4 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Now I have defined a character which satisfies $\chi(T)=\chi(R)=e^{2\pi i /8}=\zeta_{8}$. Can we find any good formula to compute 
$$
\chi\begin{pmatrix} a& b\\ 4c & d\end{pmatrix}=\zeta_{8}^{\epsilon(\gamma)}
$$
where $\epsilon(\gamma)=\epsilon\left(\begin{smallmatrix} a&b \\4c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right)\in \mathbb{Z}$? Actually, for the character which represents transformation law of Dedekind eta function, there is a formula. More precisely, if $\nu:SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})\to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is a character defined by $$\nu\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}=e^{2\pi i /24}, \nu\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}=e^{-2\pi i /8}$$
has a general formula of the form 
$$
\nu\begin{pmatrix}1&b\\0&1\end{pmatrix}=e^{2b\pi i/24}, \nu\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}=e^{\pi i [\frac{a+d}{12c}-s(d,c)-\frac{1}{4}]}
$$
where
$$
s(h, k)=\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\frac{n}{k}\left(\frac{nh}{k}-\lfloor\frac{nh}{k} \rfloor-\frac{1}{2}\right)
$$
which is called Dedekind symbol.

Edit : I also want to know the structure of $\Gamma_{0}(4)$. I don't know how to generate $-I$ with these two generators.

Comment: You're going to struggle to generate $-I$ with those generators, since $T$ and $R$ are in the index 2 subgroup $\Gamma_1(4)$ of $\Gamma_0(4)$, and $-I$ isn't.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Oh, I see. Then is it true that $\Gamma_{1}(4)$ is a free group with two generators $T, R$? I just want to know is there any programs or algorithms to determine such problems.